# Cannot access props of a react web component

Tags: reactjs

I created my web component in React using `react-to-webcomponent` as follows:

```
interface Props {
    type? string;
}

const CustomComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    console.log("props", props);
    return <div>{props.type}</div>;
}

CustomComponent.propTypes = {
    type: PropTypes.string;
}

export default CustomComponent;

customElements.define("my-component", reactToWebComponent(CustomElement, React, ReactDOM));
```

I run this project using `npm start` and add `<my-component type="sometype"></my-component>` in another React application by adding `<script src="http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js" />` in index.html.  The console log shows the following:

```
props {...}
    type: "sometype"
    _reactFiber$<randomtext>: ...
    _reactProps$<randomtext>: ...
```

I add the same bundle js in an Angular app, I see the following in the console:

```
props {...}
    type: "sometype"
```

Now, I add my web component react app inside a spring boot app and perform the build.  Then I change the script src and point to `http://localhost:8080/static/js/main.<somevalue>.js`.

In the React app that is using the custom element, the console shows:

```
props {...}
    _reactFiber$<randomtext>: ...
    _reactProps$<randomtext>: ...
```

This time, I don't have direct access to `props.type` cause the `type` is found inside `_reactProps$<randomtext>`.

For the Angular app, the console only shows:

```
props {...}
    __reactContainer$<somevalue>: ...
    __zone_symbol...
    _reactListening<somevalue>: true
```

With Angular, I totally don't have access to `props.type`

How to make the props appear when the React custom element is bundled in a web app?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue.  First in the `index.tsx`, I defined the custom element as follows:

```
const CustomComponent: any = reactToWebComponent(CustomComponent, React, ReactDOM, {
    props: {
        type: String,
    }
});

customElements.define("my-component", CustomComponent)
```

Then in the `CustomComponent`,

```
interface Props {
    type? string;
}

const CustomComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    console.log("props", props);
    return <div>{props.type}</div>;
}

export default CustomComponent;
```

That's all. :)